# Riverpod 2.0 - How to handle api status codes with FutureOr and AutoDisposeAsyncNotifier?

Tags: flutter, riverpod

Just learning about Riverpod and I'm unsure about how to handle status codes from API requests.  I haven't found any good examples that handle this gracefully.  I'm working on a simplified login test to work this out:

```
final LoginAsyncProvider = AsyncNotifierProvider.autoDispose<LoginProvider, User>(() {
  return LoginProvider();
});

class LoginProvider extends AutoDisposeAsyncNotifier<User> {

  FutureOr<User> login({required String userName, required String password}) async {
    final response = await http.post(Uri.https(Api.mainDomain, Api.login));
    final json = jsonDecode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
    User _user = User.fromJson(json);
    state = AsyncData(_user);
    return _user;
  }

  @override
  FutureOr<User> build() async {
    return login(userName: "someUser", password: "somePass");  }
}
```

I want to use this in the UI in a switch statement:

```
...
    child: switch (userAsyncValue) { 
      AsyncData(:final value) => Text(text: userAsyncValue.userName),
      AsyncError() => const Text('Some Error happened'),
      _ => const CircularProgressIndicator(),
    },
...
```

Obviously this fails on the statement `final json = jsonDecode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;` when the `response.statusCode!=200` and does not return data in `response.body`.

What is the proper way to handle failures from API requests?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to distinguish AsyncNotifier methods into three categories:

- infrastructure (`build`)
- external mutators (the public API)
- internal helpers (frequently async)

`build` must always return the first value for `state`, which is mapped from the result of build (error, data, or future) into an AsyncValue. `build` should *never* be called except by the framework.

External mutators must always be `void` or `Future<void>`, and update `state`, typically by setting it first to `AsyncLoading()` and then using `AsyncValue.guard` to safely execute a function.

Internal helpers should never be called externally, and *should not* update `state` directly.  Rather, they should return their values to the caller, which also should be internal. (They might also throw.)  Hence, these are often made library-private, and marked `@protected`.

In your specific example, your `login` should return `Future<void>`, and call an internal `_login` function to do the heavy lifting, which either returns the new `User` object or throws.  Your build can also call `_login` with an initial value for the fields, and because it's inside `build`, futures and exceptions will be handled properly.

Hope this helps!  (And I should publish an article on this...)

Comment: Thanks Randal - I'll have to rethink what I'm doing here using your suggestions.  Looking forward to that article!